# Is it possible to change the order of parents/childs in an object with items?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
sum = {
  value:{ 
      a: 10,
      b: 11
  }
  value2:{ 
      a: 33,
      c: 12
  }
  ..
}
```

My object is more complex, the letters really contains objects with different values, but the key thing is that, I wish to loop through all letters that exist in every value and return objects like:

```
a:{
  value: 10,
  value2: 33
}
```

I could loop through the entire thing build a new object, but is there a more effient way of "flipping an objects order?

I only want to use the keys that are present in all value-objects, I currently get them like this, but that is not a requirement.

```
value = ['value', 'value2']
tags.forEach( (tag) =>
    keys.push(Object.keys(sum[tag]))
)
matches = _.intersection.apply(_, keys);


matches.forEach( (match) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Would map apply here maybe?

Comment: Object keys have no order. If you want a specific order you should sort the keys in array.

Comment: It's not about the order of the items in the object it's about what node is parent and what node is child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution features a reorganisation of the order of the properties.

```
grouped[kk][k] = sum[k][kk] for all elements
```

```js
var sum = {
        value: {
            a: 10,
            b: 11
        },
        value2: {
            a: 33,
            c: 12
        }
    },
    grouped = {};

Object.keys(sum).forEach(function (k) {
    Object.keys(sum[k]).forEach(function (kk) {
        grouped[kk] = grouped[kk] || {};
        grouped[kk][k] = sum[k][kk];
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```